# Want to reduce the unnecessary gaps between html tags

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I was creating my custom toast notification using react but there is unnecessary gaps between the tag because of which the size in to big 
**React Code**

```js
import React from 'react'
import './CustomToast.css'
import {BsFillBellFill} from 'react-icons/bs'
import {ImCross} from 'react-icons/im'
function useCustomToast(title,message){
    const close = () =>{
        alert('closed')
    }
    return(
        <div className="notification">
            <div className="topPart">
                <div className="iconPoision">
                    <p><BsFillBellFill/></p>
                </div>
                <div className="notifiData">
                    <p><b>{title}</b></p>
                </div>
                <div className="crossPosition">
                    <p><button onClick={close} className="closeButton"><ImCross/></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="downPart">
                <p>{message}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**The Code's CSS**

```css
.notification{
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 234, 0.726);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.562);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap:2px;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;   
}
.topPart{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 2px;
    grid-template-columns: 22px auto 25px;
}
.downPart{
    display: grid;
    grid-column: auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    text-align: right;
}
.notifiData{
    text-align: left;
}
.iconPoision{
    text-align: center;
}
.closeButton{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition:ease-out;
}
.crossPosition{
    text-align: center;
}
```

So, if i remove the space between them the notification panel will be some small and which looks like a notification type only

**See so much of empty space between top and bottom row**
[image]

Comment: for this kind of detailed styling, you should use inspect element and edit on the chrome dev tools firsthand before committing to code the css.

Comment: Ouuu.. i see that's for giving me this GK ... thanks a lot sir @KevinMoeMyintMyat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to your './CustomToast.css' and modify it as needed.

```
p { 
  padding: 0 0; 
  margin: 0 0;
}
```

Change p with any other tag as div, span etc